# Creating navigation bar with categories in magento

Tags: magento-2.0

I am creating  a Magento shop , right now shop have no navigation bar. I want to add a navigation bar on the top of the page using the categories hierarchy I created. Or just tell me how to create a navigation manually or add it through some widget. Please.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Luma Theme (the default magento2 theme), the top navigation should automatically appear after you create your categories. You can check the following guide: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-top.html

If you want to create custom navigation you can check this page: 
http://icecubedigital.com/blog/how-to-create-a-cms-page-in-magento-2-and-add-its-link-to-top-navigation-menu/

Comment: I followed the tutorials you mentioned above , but now the categories a displayed in the form of a drop-down along side with search text box. I want to show them as nav bar on the top.  What to do for that